# Postgres replication on specific tables.

Tags: database-replication, sharding, postgresql-9.4

i have a sharded database (Postgres 9.4). I want data from some tables (4 or 5 tables with relatively rare updates) to be replicated through all the shards, but other tables shouln't be replicated at all. What is the best way to do this?

- Can it be done using only the Postgres functionality?
- What plugins may be used if not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: pg_shard might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_shard

Answer (score 0):

With streaming replication that is not possible.